# django-auth-ldap query. Cannot add LDAP users to active, staff, superuser roles

Tags: python, django, authentication, openldap, django-auth-ldap

Looking for some help with the django-auth-ldap package.

Background - I am trying to add LDAP users to the default user roles STAFF, ACTIVE, and SUPERUSER. As you can no doubt see from the the debug.log that the django-auth-ldap successfully finds the LDAP username and populates DJANGO accordingly.

However it does not add the LDAP user to the relevant roles i.e.active, staff, superuser, because it states that it does not belong to the relevant group although performing an LDAP search on both the username and group says otherwise.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

#### debug.log

```
search_s('ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk', 2, '(uid=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=someusername,ou=xx,ou=xxxxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk

Populating Django user someusername

cn=someusername,ou=xxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,o=xx,c=uk is not a member of cn=somegroup,ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk

cn=someusername,ou=xxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,o=xx,c=uk is not a member of cn=somegroup,ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk

cn=someusername,ou=xxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,o=xx,c=uk is not a member of cn=somegroup,ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk
```

#### settings.py

```
import os
import ldap
import logging
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType, PosixGroupType

** Omitted for clarity **


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldaps://ldap.xxxxxxxxxxx.xx.uk/"
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk"

# Application definition
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
 ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: False,
 ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: False,
}

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldaps://ldap.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.uk"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk",    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=somegroup,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk",
    "is_staff": "cn=somegroup,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk",
    "is_superuser": "cn=somegroup,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk"
}


** Omitted for clarity**
```

#### Output from LDAP group search### (some lines omitted)

```
# ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.xxxxxxxxxxx.xx.uk/  cn=somegroup
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: cn=somegroup
# requesting: ALL
#

# somegroup, xx, xxx, xxxx, xx, uk
dn: cn=somegroup,ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
member;x-static:cn=someusername,ou=xxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,o=xx,c=uk

cn:somegroup
```

#### Output from LDAP username search ### (some lines omitted)

```
# ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.xxxxxxxxxxx.xx.uk/  cn=someusername

someusername, xxxx, xxx, xxx, xx, uk
dn: cn=someusername,ou=xxxx,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,o=xx,c=uk
uniqueID: someusername
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: ndsLoginProperties
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: posixGroup
groupMembership: cn=somegroup,ou=xx,ou=xxx,ou=xxxx,o=xx,c=uk
cn: someusername
```

Comment: Enable logging for the django-ldap module and check the log.

Comment: have you solved this ? i am getting the same issue